# Delete a database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

By mistake, I have created a duplicate database in the phpMyAdmin page of cPanel. I want to delete this database, but I am not able to find any delete button in the UI.

How to delete a database in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

After successful login to cPanel, near to the `phpMyAdmin` icon there is another icon `MySQL Databases`; click on that.

[image]

That brings you to the database listing page.

In the action column you can find the `delete database` option click on that to delete your database!

Comment: This is outdated. There is no action column in the phpMyAdmin that I'm using... Please update your answer.

Comment: Why assume that everyone uses cPanel? And why give a cPanel answer to a PHPmyAdmin question?

Comment: @MAwg you are absolutely right, i agree with you.
As the use mention on his question that "I have created a duplicate database in the phpMyAdmin page of cPanel"
that why i gave cpanel answer

Answer (score 142):

On **phpMyAdmin 4.1.9**:

`database_name > Operations > Remove database`

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth - not available within the PHP MyAdmin window I'm getting from my ISP :(

Comment: If it is not in your PHPMyAdmin, you might have another option off your cPannel, "My SQL Databases". My ISP uses 2 different links for options that are available in PHPMyAdmin on other ISPs

Comment: IMHO, it is only availabe for users with global privilage to drop the database. Otherwise, simply it wont be there. I checked in local enviornment, IMHO, it might be in production enviornment too.

Comment: any reason why they just don't have a 'delete' button in a more intuitive location?  Llike the databases homepage.

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? The accepted answer is about deleting it in cpanel - NOT about deleting from phpmyadmin which is what the question asked, and the question I was actually looking for the answer to. And, this worked by the way. In cpanel for some reason, those databases were not showing up, my reason for searching for this.

Answer (score 30):

[image: Screenshot]

1. Go to phpmyadmin home page.
2. Click on 'Databases'.
3. Select the database you want to delete. (put check mark)
4. Click Drop.

Comment: there are  no such options on server side  and you should quit the  phpmyadmin and delete the db entirely from hosting's panel on server.

Answer (score 23):

Taking a queue from michael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035555/2491276) above, I was unable to find the DROP Database command on my `phpMyAdmin` console in the `localhost`.

Apparantly I was missing a setting. Go to `config.inc.php` file of the `phpMyAdmin` folder, and add this:

`$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;`

Save and restart the local server and the command appears inside the console.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to delete your database from phpmyAdmin or mySQl. Simply go to SQL command and write command "drop DATABASE databasename;"

Example: `drop DATABASE rainbowonlineshopping;`

[image]

Then click on "Go" Button. Your Database will be deleted and you get information like this

[image]

Comment: there are no drop or delete buttons in my new phpmyadmin. So this answer still the only correct.  **2020 y**

Comment: On Siteground even this is disabled. But Googling specifically for Siteground gives a tutorial (horribly long URL, and it may change) that one does it in Site Tools. When doing domain transfers this does have the advantage that one can see which site one is on, which is not the case within PHPmyAdmin.

Answer (score 7):

You  can delete the database in Cpanel.

In Cpanel go to databases and there you will see all created databases and you can delete this database.

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/MySQLDatabases#Delete a Database

or other wise on live server  if user have privileges you can run command in sql tab of phpmyadmin.

```
drop database databasename;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can follow uploaded images

[image]

Then select which database you want to delete

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. Connect to your localhost.
2. Open your favorite browser.
3. Make sure your localhost is working.
4. Type in url= localhost.
5. Scroll down click on phpadmin once phpadmin is open.
6. Click on database.
7. Mark check the database you want remove.
8. Click on drop.

**If this don't work**

1. Click on database go to operation
2. Click drop database

[image]

Answer (score 4):

database_name -> Operations -> Remove database -> click on drop the database (DROP)

Answer (score 4):

Follow the following steps to delete database in PhpMyAdmin.

1. Select your database.
2. Choose the "Operations" tab.
3. On this page under remove database, you will find a "Drop the database (DROP)"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways for delete Database

1. Run this SQL query -> DROP DATABASE database_name
2. Click database_name -> Operations ->Remove Database

Answer (score 3):

Open the `Terminal` and run

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

Password is null or just enter your mysql password

Ater Just Run This Query

```
 DROP DATABASE DBname;
```

---

*If you are using phpmyadmin then just run*

```
 DROP DATABASE DBname;
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to delete a database in phpMyAdmin?

From the Operations tab of the database, look for (and click) the text `Drop the database (DROP)`.

Answer (score 2):

select database on the left side. Then on the right-central top you can find Operations. In that go for remove database (DROP). That's all.

Answer (score 2):

The delete / drop option in operations is not present in my version.

Go to CPanel ->  MySQLDatabase (icon next to PhPMyAdmin) -> check the DB to be delete -> delete.

Answer (score 1):

Go to operations tab for the selected database and click "Drop the database (DROP)" to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It will work 100%. Go to your xampp installation directory.

```
`D:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php`
```

Steps:

Step1: Go the line number 777 and  replace this

```
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = false; to $cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;
```

Step2: restart the xampp

[image: Problem image]

[image: Solution Image]

Comment: superb solution.