# how can i delete the database that i am in it in mysql? without knowing the name of the database DROP DATABASE()

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i delete the current database?

```
DROP DATABASE()
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

this is the error that i get

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751868/delete-a-database-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DROP DATABASE dbname` syntax.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html)

Comment: yes i know but how can i do it when i dont know the name?

Comment: You mean what? Dynamically dropping or without knowing anything ? If you mean second that is not possible. You have to indicate dbname.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @q = CONCAT('DROP DATABASE ', DATABASE(), ';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

All precautions that apply to any statement involving a `DROP`, and especially a `DROP DATABASE`, apply here too, and then some.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax:

```
DROP DATABASE databasename;
```

Comment: yes i know but how can i do it when i dont know the name?